# Write the characteristic polynomial of the orthogonal projection $P: \mathbb{R} ^ 5 \rightarrow \mathbb {R} ^ 5$ on the plane $W$.

Tags: linear-algebra

We consider $\mathbb {R} ^ 5$ with the usual Euclidean product. Let $W \subset \mathbb {R} ^ 5$ be a two-dimensional subspace. Write the characteristic polynomial of the orthogonal projection $P: \mathbb{R} ^ 5 \rightarrow \mathbb {R} ^ 5$ on the plane $W$.

Could you give me any hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be nice to know what tools you have available, as that will affect what hints are appropriate. What have you tried to do on this problem? What theorems do you personally think might be relevant?

Comment: Yes, I know all of the things you have mentioned.

Comment: But unfortunately, I don't know which theorems could fit in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U_1,U_2$ an orthogonal basis of the plane. Let $V_1,V_2,V_3$ an orthogonal complement of this basis.

The $V_k$ are eigenvectors of $P$ associated with eigenvalues $0$ because $PV_K=0=0V_k$ (otherwise said, they are in the kernel of $P$).

The $U_k$ are eigenvectors of $P$ associated with eigenvalues $1$ (because $PU_k=U_k=1U_k$ (they are aleready projected... onto themselves)

Therefore the spectrum of $P$ (multi)set $\{0,0,0,1,1\}$, and its characteristic polynomial is :

$$\chi(\lambda)=-\lambda^3(\lambda-1)^2$$

(please note the minus sign due to the fact that we are in an odd dimension).

Comment: Thanks. And do you know in this case, which could be the characteristic polynomial of the orthogonal symmetry S: R5 ---> R5 over the W plane?

Comment: I am tempted to answer : "replace the three zero eigenvalues by three eigenvalues $-1$" BUT  the concept of symmetry with respect to a plane (dimension 2) which is not an hyperplane (dimension 4 here) might be controversial...

Answer (score 0):

The restriction of any projection to its image is the identity map, so $1$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $\ge\dim W = 2$. By the same token, this orthogonal projection annihilates $W^\perp$, so $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $\ge\dim W^\perp = 5-\dim W=3$. That brings the total multiplicity to at least $5$, so we’ve accounted for all of the eigenvalues. The characteristic polynomial is therefore $\lambda^3(\lambda-1)^2$.